# Reading appsettings.json in .net core only works in HomeController

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I my .net core MVC application, when I read appsettings.json from the HomeController it works but in other classes, the AppSettings objects is never initialized.

Can anyone find out whats wrong?

I've created my custom class AppSettings where property name are mapped to the section in appsettings.json.

I've included this in the Startup.cs.

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

It works in the HomeController:

```
 private static AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

    public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
    {
        AppSettings = settings.Value;
    }

    private void TestMethod()
    {
        // This works inside the HomeController
        var dbString = AppSettings.DataBaseConnectionString;
    }
```

This constructor in BusinessLogic class will however never been called:

```
private static AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

    public BusinessLogic(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
    {
        AppSettings = settings.Value;
    }
    private void TestMethod()
    {
        // This does NOT work inside the BusinessLogic class. Appsettings is null.
        var dbString = AppSettings.DataBaseConnectionString;
    }
```

Comment: is your "BusinessLogic" class and "HomeController" are in the same project ?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same project.

Comment: You are injecting the settings object into the constructor. For this to work, you should register the BusinessLogic class as a service in your IoC Container. Is that the case? Where is this BusinessLogic class used?

Comment: The BLogic class is called directly from HomeC, everything lives in the same MVC project. HomeController.cs is in folder Controllers, as it is in a standard MVC project. BusinessLogic.cs is in another folder called Logic and this class is only called upon from other parts in this solution. Why does the same code work in HomeC but not i BLogic? I'm doing it the exact same way and does not register HomeC in any special way. I can't really answer you on the IoC Container, that term is new to me.

Comment: services.AddOptions(); Did you add it?

Answer (score 0):

You can register your class to DI system in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddTransient<BusinessLogic>();
```

Then you can inject the class in anywhere , for example in controller :

```
private readonly BusinessLogic _businessLogic ;

public HomeController(BusinessLogic businessLogic) {
    _businessLogic = businessLogic;
}
```

You can read about the different lifetime and registration options :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: Sorry for being a little slow, but why would I have to use the BusinessLogic class inside the HomeController? I mean, HomeC is just receiving the requests, then call a method in BLogic, then BLogic will call DatabaseLogic, ADLogic and so on. I just want each of these classes to be able to reach information from appsettings.json. It seems like a bad solution if the classes must inject one another just in order to reach appsettings.json.

Comment: where do you want to call `BusinessLogic` class ? You just need to inject `BusinessLogic` as shown above , using BusinessLogic in controller is just a code sample , you could do what you want based on your requirement .

Comment: Maybe I'm unclear, or I does not understand what you mean with "where do you want to call BusinessLogic class ?" From my HomeController, I can just write "BusinessLogic.MyMethod()" and then the breakpoint in MyMethod() in BusinessLogic class hits. The problem is not to reach BusinessLogic, the problem is for BusinessLogic to get values from appsettings.json. From my understanding, this is a problem between BLogic and appsettings.json (and some things like Startup.cs) a and has nothing to do with the HomeC at all.

Comment: try my codes to inject BusinessLogic in controller , then use `_businessLogic.MyMethod()` , check whether you can get the appsetting values .

Comment: It worked. I had to add services.AddTransient<BusinessLogic>(); a couple of times, one for each of my classes where I wanted to read from appsettings.json. Then, I had to pass in each of them classes in the HomeController constructor. Thank you so much for your help. One thing is however nagging me, is it really the correct way to do this coding in the HomeController? What if I have ProductController as well? It will be a lot of references and unnecessary coding in my opinion, also some hard coded dependencies to.

Comment: that is the correct way , the DI system will handle the dependency graph and manage that according to the lifetime you config . please check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for better understanding .I don't understand the "unnecessary coding" , you will inject it if you want to use it .